# change background color via CSS after a certain width

Tags: css, reactjs

I made a program in react js ,to analyze user microphone volume. The volume range can be in between 1 - 20;
so in order to show it on the UI ,I'm just multiplying it with 5 and setting it as the width
percentage of a div.
my code :

```
<div id="default_audio_view">
      <div
        className="_inside_default_view"
        style={{ width: `${volume * 5}%` }}
      ></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#default_audio_view {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
._inside_default_view {
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgb(32, 235, 32) 0 29.3%,
    rgb(255, 255, 24) 33.3% 62.6%,
    rgb(221, 16, 16) 66.6% 100%
  );
}
```

Now the `linear gradient` considering only the `_inside_default_view's` width as 100%. How can I solve it?

[image: it's the result]

Comment: Could you share your generated ```html``` ?

Comment: and how is your expected output should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another background for a full-width colorful bar on a new element called `_inside_default_view_background`, and use the existing `_inside_default_view` with a grey right-to-left background like below

```css
#default_audio_view {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
._inside_default_view {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}

._inside_default_view_background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgb(32, 235, 32) 0 29.3%,
    rgb(255, 255, 24) 33.3% 62.6%,
    rgb(221, 16, 16) 66.6% 100%
  );
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="default_audio_view">
  <div class="_inside_default_view" style="width: 50%;"></div>
  <div class="_inside_default_view_background"></div>
</div>
```

With the above technique, you also need to modify your formula from 100% to back (instead of 0% to 100%)

```
<div id="default_audio_view">
      <div
        className="_inside_default_view"
        style={{ width: `${100 - (volume * 5)}%` }}
      ></div>
      <div class="_inside_default_view_background"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arijit you'll need to dynamically update the style based on state, you could also use the `animate` method in JS, though browser support might be spotty for it as it's still fairly new at the time of writing this.